# How to disable SwiftUI animations in UITests?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uitest

I tried to disable animation in UITests with the following code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchEnvironment = ["DISABLE_ANIMATIONS": "1"]
```

I also tried:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
```

But it doesn't disable animation when I run UITests on simulator.

Is it because I'm using SwiftUI ?

The animation I want to disable is a view transition from one SwiftUI View to another one. Here is how I coded the transition:

```
NavigationLink(destination: MapView(), isActive: $viewModel.isDataLoaded) {
     EmptyView()
}
```

Is there another way to disable animation in UITests when using SwiftUI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to be done explicitly (by-code) in main application, because UITests run in different process, ie. it should be like

```
struct YourApp: App {
    init() {
        let env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
        if env["DISABLE_ANIMATIONS"] == "1" {          // << here !!
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
      // ... scene here
    }
}
```

and then it can be used

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchEnvironment = ["DISABLE_ANIMATIONS": "1"]
```

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Comment: Correct answer. The Asker should mark it as accepted.

Comment: This does not work for SwiftUI-native animations, unfortunately: Neither `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` nor `window.layer.speed = 100` seem to have any effect on animations that use [withAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:_:)). I haven't found a solution yet that really covers SwiftUI and not only the parts that are backed by UIKit.

Comment: I have tried ```transaction.disablesAnimations = true``` on the top level ```ContentView()```, but it does not propagate all the way down the view hierarchy, either.

Comment: @DanielSeither did you eventually find a solution to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, but I'd still be interested in any approaches that change the animation speed or switch off animations globally.